# Formatting Bash output into one Table

Tags: bash, output-formatting

I have this line of Code
which produces the first half of my table. The last half of the Table are the Sizes from 
the hdd's . So first this is my code right now:

```
function getiSCSI() {
    for host in ${allhosts} ; do
        HOSTID="$( echo "${host}" | awk -F, '{print$1}' )"
        CSV_FQDN="$( echo "${host}" | awk -F, '{print$2}' )"
        ALLORACLEDEV=$(ssh -x -l root ${CSV_FQDN} '/sbin/multipath -ll'  | grep NETAPP|awk '{print $2}')
        for i in $ALLORACLEDEV ; do 
            ( ssh -x -l root ${CSV_FQDN} "fdisk -l /dev/$i|grep GB" |awk '{print $3,$4}'
                )
            done ;ssh -x -l root ${CSV_FQDN} "ls -l /dev/oracleasm/disks/|grep dm-[0-9]"|awk '{print $11, $9}'|cut -d/ -f3

    done #2>/dev/null #| ${GENHTML_CMD}

}
```

The output right now looks like this:

```
107.4 GByte,
107.4 GByte,
107.4 GByte,
107.4 GByte,
107.4 GByte,
107.4 GByte,
107.4 GByte,
107.4 GByte,
107.4 GByte,
dm-18 arch01
dm-16 na2lun01
dm-17 na2lun02
dm-21 na2lun03
dm-19 na2lun04
dm-20 na2lun05
dm-22 na2lun06
dm-23 na2lun07
dm-28 na2lun08
```

But i want the table like this:

```
dm-18 arch01   107.4 GByte
dm-16 na2lun01 107.4 GByte
dm-17 na2lun02 107.4 GByte
dm-21 na2lun03 107.4 GByte
dm-19 na2lun04 107.4 GByte
dm-20 na2lun05 107.4 GByte
dm-22 na2lun06 107.4 GByte
dm-23 na2lun07 107.4 GByte
dm-28 na2lun08 107.4 GByte
```

I tried all the Stuff i know about bash but my knowledge about bash script is very small :\
Could you help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your output to two different files (file1, file2),
and them paste them together using paste.

```
paste file1 file2
```

Or you can do it directly on the fly:

```
paste <( command1 ) <( command2 )
```